# Proof of differential operator identity in DLMF $16.3.5$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-operators

DLMF $16.3.5$ gives the differential operator identity
$$
(z\partial_z z)^nf(z)=z^n\partial_z^nz^nf(z),\quad n=1,2,\dots
$$
where $\partial_z$ is differentiation w.r.t. $z$. I am having some issues proving this identity.  It seems like this is a candidate for induction.  Clearly, the identity holds for $n=1$ so assuming for $n$ we have
$$
(z\partial_z z)^{n+1}=z\partial_z z^{n+1}\partial_z^nz^n.
$$
At this point all I had to go on was trying to somehow use the product rule.  I wrote
$$
(z\partial_z z)^{n+1}=z\partial_z (z^{n+1}\partial_z^nz^n)=z((n+1)z^n\partial_z^nz^n+z^{n+1}\partial_z^{n+1}z^n),
$$
which seems to lead to a dead end. How do I prove this identity? Perhaps a different proof technique altogether?

Comment: Is $z=x+i y$? If not and it is a real variable then isn't $\partial^{n+1}_z z^n = 0$?

Comment: @808GroundState Yes $z$ is real.  I will add that. In regards to your question, $\partial_z^{n+1}z^n\neq 0$ because what this is an operator applied to a function so it really means $\partial_z^{n+1}z^nf(z)$

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, I see they are operators now. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Proving it for all $f(x)=x^k$ should be enough.

Comment: It is proven in https://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9403002.pdf (the reference comes from the DLMF itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the linear operators
$\, D(f) \!:=\! \partial_z f, \, Z(f) \!:=\! z f \,$ with
$\, DZ(f) \!=\! f \!+\! Z D(f) .\,$ Since the operators
$\, Z D\,$ and $\,DZ\,$ differ by the identity operator,
they commute. Moreover, we can prove that
$\,Z D\,$ and $\,D^n Z^n\,$ commute for all $\,n\,$ by
induction.

Using simple algebra and a few steps we can prove that
$$ Z DZ(Z^n D^n Z^n) \!=\! Z^{n+1}((n\!+\!1)D^n Z^n \!+\!Z D^{n+1}Z^n). \tag{1} $$ But now, again using simple algebra,
$$ Z^{n+1}D^{n+1}Z^{n+1}\!=\!
Z^{n+1}((n\!+\!1)D^n Z^n + D^n Z^{n+1}D). \tag{2}$$
Since $\,Z D\,$ and $\,D^n Z^n\,$ commute, the two quantities
on the right side of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal. Thus, $\,(Z DZ)^n = Z^n D^n Z^n$ for all $\,n\,$
by induction.